# Calculating a probability distribution of volume

Tags: probability, statistics

Given that volume, $V = L \times W \times H$, $L \geq W$, $W \geq H$, $V \leq x$, where $x$ is a real, non negative number.

The probability of $L$ is a uniform probability distribution between $\left(0, y\right)$, e.g. $P(L) = \frac{1}{y}$. For example, the probability of $L <= \frac{y}{2}$ is 50%, the probability of $L <= \frac{y}{4}$ is 25%, etc. The probability of W and H are uniform distributions as well. What is the probability distribution of $V$, Volume?

So far I know the probability of $V \gt y^3$ is $0$, $P(V \geq x) =0 $, and $ P(V \leq 0) = 0$. I can also run a simulation a billion times and get a distribution for V, but I'm not sure how to arrive at the conclusion mathematically due to my limited knowledge of probability.

Furthermore, if the probability distribution of $L$ is a Gamma distribution with $k = \frac{y}{2}$, what is the probability distribution of $V$, Volume?

Thank you for reading, much appreciate the help! Will validate answers with Matlab simulations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please provide more context to your problem, what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: The probability distribution of a quantity that cannot be negative cannot be exactly Gaussian. Perhaps you can approximate that Gaussian by a gamma distribution with the same expected value and variance.

Comment: Edited for clarity and the fact that Gaussian function can be negative while the quantity must be positive.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the derivation of the final cdf/pdf is going to be quite lengthy I will provide some hints and initial steps and I would recommend that you go through some good resource for the subject, as this type of question is pretty common. I would recommend https://www.probabilitycourse.com/ or the book probabilty random variables and stochastic processes by A Papoulis, So we can write our final requirement to find the cumulative distribution function as $P(V\leq v)$ where $V=wlh$ and to find the probability we integrate wrt the random variable of $w,l,h$, but we have to take care of the range of the random variables while integrating to find the probability, to provide the first step we can convert it into $P(w\leq \frac{v}{lh})$ where $w$ is our dependent variable and its integration range depends on $l,h$ similarly as we proceed we find some conditions on the ranges of  $l,h$  on which we will integrate. After finding the cdf differentiate wrt $v$ to find pdf.

Comment: Thanks will check it out!